# Validate string format pattern for logger.log in IntelliJ 13.1

Tags: java, intellij-13

IntelliJ 13.1 has a nice feature which validates that the number of parameters referenced from the string pattern in String.format(pattern, params) matches the number of passed parameters.

Is there a way to configure IntelliJ to do the same for other methods, such as sl4j [logger.error(String, params)](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#error(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method?